# How did US, and the Western world's people react when USSR suddenly became an ally during WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union, cold-war, propaganda

Before the USSR's participation in WWII with the West, it had a non-aggression pact with Germany, invaded Poland, and is basically the super-villain of the Red Scare. But suddenly, after USSR became an ally, the Western propaganda posters started saying: "This man (Russian Soldier) is your friend, He defends Freedom". How did such a value dissonance impacted the western civilians? What do they think about such a abrupt transition that a "super-evil Joseph Stalin" is now "Uncle Joe"?

Comment: Was Joseph Stalin portrayed as "super-evil" in the west prior to WW2?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  Concur with @SteveBird that Stalin = Super Evil presumes facts not in evidence.  My memory is that prior to the [Doctor's Plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctors%27_plot) Stalin was perceived positively in US elite circles.   Might be worth digging into the assumptions here.  Seems like there ought to be sources to pull news coverage

Comment: My relatives viewed it as a marriage of convenience at best…

Comment: Isn't the idea that "my enemy's enemy is my friend" almost as old as conflict?

Comment: You are misusing the "red scare" terminology. The first one followed the end of ww1, the second followed the end of ww2....

Comment: There's a decent amount about this from Winston Churchill's perspective in his [autobiography of WWII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Second_World_War_(book_series)).

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike The second red scare was a bit after WW2, and was triggered more by the Chinese situation of 1949-1950.

Comment: For the perspective of the question, it should be noted that the Soviets were pulled into WW2 before the Americans.  Lend Lease was extended to them in October 1941.  Further, American strategic interest was focused on the Pacific and western Europe, and less in eastern Europe.  Therefore having the Soviets as a "comrade" didn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Your question is based on false premises. These kinds of deals and territory shifts were normal at the time and didn't set the USSR apart from other nations. Certainly much less than communism did.

Comment: @Smith: Yes, I know. But for the purpose of my comment it was irrelevant and I decided not to get to the details.

Comment: Didn't Poland also have a [non-aggression pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German–Polish_declaration_of_non-aggression) with Nazi Germany?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo - Not according to the Germans. They insisted from the start [it wasn't a "pact", but merely a "declaration"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German%E2%80%93Polish_declaration_of_non-aggression#Naming), which tells you how seriously they intended to take it. Germany demanded a "renegotiation" of it in exchange for Danzig about a year before the invasion, and repudiated it entirely 4 months prior.

Comment: @T.E.D. It still lasted longer than the pact with the Soviet Union.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo - "Taken more seriously than the M-R Pact" isn't exactly a high bar, but I'll give that one to you.